# How to enable dropdowns while checkbox checked using Angular

Tags: angular

Have datatable and table contains two dropdowns(disabled mode) for every columns. While checkbox checked need to enable dropdowns. Im able to enable only dropdown, second dropdown box not enabled. Tried below code, could you please help me how to enable dropdowns,

```
<td><input [(ngModel)]="person.check" [checked]="isChecked" type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls"></td>

<td>
     <select [disabled]="!person.check?true:null" [(ngModel)]="person.test2">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
     </select>
 </td>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-y5thc6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the columns in dtOptions is working fine.

```
this.dtOptions = {
          processing: true,
          destroy: true,
          columns: [
            { name: "" },
            { data: "index" },
            { title: "Dropdown" },
            { title: "Dropdown2" },
            { data: "firstname" },
            { data: "lastname" }
      ]
  };
```

Comment: Yeah got it, I rearranged as per the above, working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is that `DataTableDirective` but if you remove your `dtOptions` from table, your code works like the expected behavior. So you need to fix `dtOptions` columns I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
[disabled]="!person.checked"
```

This should work fine